# Can start ChromeDriver within CLI tool but won't allow connections

Tags: laravel, selenium-chromedriver, homestead

I'm using Laravel homestead and I'm writing a little artisan command line tool that I need to browse my site with javascript execution.

I run dusk test regularly with no difficulty, so I thought I would use Laravel's tools for this script.

I started out by running this early in my script:

```
\Laravel\Dusk\TestCase::startChromeDriver();
```

This started the driver fine running on port 9515 running as user `vagrant` (default homestead user)

But when I tried to access it (also from within the script) I would get an error:

`Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused`

If I instead started it manually on the command line:

`$ ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --port=9515`

The driver started fine again running on port 9515 as user `vagrant`, but this time my tool runs fine.

But I really want to be able to start the ChromeDriver from within the tool. So I also tried:

```
$process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process('./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --port=9515');
$process->start();
```

Connection was refused again.

Any idea why this works when I start it from the command line but not within my artisan command?

Comment: How are you accessing chromedriver from your artisan command? When Laravel creates a new RemoteWebDriver for a Browser it uses `retry(5, function(){}, 50)` to try connecting 5 times, waiting 50ms between each. Are you using the Dusk browser, or do you have your own implementation?

Comment: Hi Travis, I'm using the Dusk Browser which works fine if I start the chromedriver manually (from outside of the script). But I've noticed that `Process` launches the driver using `sh -c /path/to/driver`

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why this makes a difference but it has. If I launch the driver with the full path:

`/home/vagrant/Code/mysite/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --port=8888`

all works fine now.